# Serial com port (serial) communication with scanner using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I need to receive data from a scanner device using serial communitation (COM port). I need to receive the data byte by byte using C#. How can I do it?

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this question is nearly un-answerable because you have provided no details about the device that you need to pull data from. Each device is different, they contain many different parameters that you need to know such as baud rate, the type of handshake being used, the parity, the data bits, and the stop bits. Without knowing these things there is no way to establish communication, which prevents you from getting data altogether. You can not just plug anything into a COM port and expect to be able to extract data from it.

Depending on the scanner device you are using, there is usually some sort of manual or help website for the device itself that contains a list of commands that can be sent to the scanning device. You need to reference the namespace `System.IO.Ports` and use the methods inside there to connect to device.

Basically, after establishing a connection, you will be sending commands that are recognized by the device to the device and will receive information back.

There is plenty of information how to do this online

Here is a link to the information on the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports(v=vs.110).aspx

And if that isn't self explanatory by itself, then here is a video on how to accomplish this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Rp_nPApHbU

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `System.IO.Ports` namespace. In there you can use the `SerialPort` class and create one bound to `COM1`.

From there you can read an array of bytes using the `BaseStream` property or the `ReadByte` method.